# Error, when inserting key/value in the Map object, using forEach ()

Tags: javascript

I created a class to register points within my Map, but when looping with forEach (), nothing is returned

```
class PtsPeriods {
    constructor( ptsFrist=0, ptsSecund=0, ptsThird=0 )  { 
        const periods = new Map();

        let args = [...arguments];
        
        args.forEach((cur, index) => { periods.set(index++,cur);})
    
    }
};
```

Recording the data:

```
const AllTeams = new Map();

function registerTeam(simbol=" ", team, pts1, pts2, pts3) {
    AllTeams.set(`${simbol} ${team}`, new PtsPeriods(pts1,pts2,pts3));
}

registerTeam("","bulls",10,20,30);

console.log(AllTeams);
```

The result in the log is `Map (1) {" bulls" => Pt Periods}` with `PtsPeriods` being an empty object.

```
{" bulls" => PtsPeriodo}
    key: " bulls"
    value: PtsPeriodo {}
```

the expected result is

```
{" bulls" => Map (3)}
    key: " bulls"
    value: Map (3) {1 => 10, 2 => 20, 3 => 30}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is that your class constructor is not assigning the value to the instance, it only creates an empty object, you should change your constructor:

```
class PtsPeriods {
    constructor( ptsFrist=0, ptsSecund=0, ptsThird=0 )  { 
        this.periods = new Map();

        let args = [...arguments];
        
        args.forEach((cur, index) => { this.periods.set(index++,cur);})
    
    }
};
```

That way you will be assigning the values to the class instance.